# Non Atomic Batch Failure in Derby Update

Tags: java, derby

What is Non Atomic Batch Failure in derby update via `stmt.executeBatch()` ?

Sorry for the downvote. But I've got the error.: I wrote the code like this: `stmt.executeBatch(query);`. Actually `stmt.executeBatch();` is correct.

In another code I set `setAutoCommit(false)` and forgot to make it `setAutoCommit(true)` The Message disappeared when I corrected these two.

Answer (score 1):

It means "something went wrong" in an non-atomic batch.  The "non-atomic batch" bit means (I think) that the batch involved multiple transactions and couldn't be rolled back in its entirety.

The complete exception message most likely is something like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.derby.client.am.BatchUpdateException: 
    Non-atomic batch failure. The batch was submitted, but at least one 
    exception occurred on an individual member of the batch. Use getNextException() 
    to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements.
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.Agent.endBatchedReadChain(Agent.java:267)
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeBatchRequestX(PreparedStatement.java:1596)
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeBatchX(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:945)
        at AOIB.main(AOIB.java:24)
```

It says (in effect) "One or more of the operations in the batch failed.  I can't tell you which, but you can find out by calling `getNextException()`."

Comment: It means "something went wrong"  I know that . But why this this happens?

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara - We can't tell you that because the exception message doesn't say.  You need to call `getNextException()` and print it to find out ... like the message tells you to do.

Comment: For more assistance interpreting your exceptions: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain